# How can an Alloy constraint put a set inside its subset?

Tags: alloy

The following Alloy code says that each hotel room has a set of keys:

```
sig Key {}

sig Room {
    keys: set Key
}
```

The `keys` relation needs to be constrained. As it stands, it permits instances such as this: key K1 is used in a bunch of rooms. Ouch! We don't want that. We want each key to be used only with one room. Here's a graphic illustrating the universe of valid instances (and the subset of instances that we actually want to allow):

[image: Universe of room/key instances]

The set of instances that we actually want is nicely expressed with this Alloy code:

```
Room lone -> Key
```

The instances for that Alloy code is depicted in the above graphic by the small circle.

So, how do we constrain `keys`? One answer is this: create an Alloy fact which says this:

```
keys in Room lone -> Key
```

Think about what that is graphically saying. It is saying that the big circle must be inside the little circle (see below). Isn't that weird? How can a circle be inside its sub-circle? Can someone give me some intuition about this please? It seems odd.

[image: Big circle inside small circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you only have `sig Room {keys: set Key}` without any additional facts/constraints, the domain for the `keys` relation is the big circle;
- you can decide to add some constraints (like `keys in Room lone -> Key`) exactly for the purpose of shrinking the domain for the `keys` relation (so that it becomes the small circle).

So the right way to think about it is not that the big circle must be inside the small circle (?!); rather, think of it as using the small circle instead of the big circle as the domain (set of all valid values) for `keys`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Aleksandar Milicevic!